# Compute Higher Moments of Data Matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

this probably leads to scipy/numpy, but right now I'm happy with any functionality as I couldn't find anything in those packages. I have a matrix that contains data for a multi-variate distribution (let's say, 2, for the fun of it). Is there any function to compute (higher) moments of that? All I could find was numpy.mean() and numpy.cov() :o

Thanks :)

/edit:

So some more detail: I have multivariate data, that is, a matrix where rows display variables and columns observations. Now I would like to have a simple way of computing the joint moments of that data, as defined in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_moment#Multivariate_moments . 
I'm pretty new to python/scipy so I'm not sure I'd be the best person to code this one up, especially for the n-variables case (note that the wikipedia definition is for n=2), and I kind of expected there to be some out-of-the-box thing to use as I thought this would be a standard problem.

/edit2:

Just for the future, in case someone wants to do something similar, the following code (which is still under review) should give the sample equivalent of the raw moments E(X^2), E(Y^2), etc. It only works for two variables right now, but it should be extendable if one feels the need. If you see some mistakes or unclean/unpython-nish code, feel free to comment.

```
from numpy import *

# this function should return something as
# moments[0] = 1
# moments[1] = mean(X), mean(Y)
# moments[2] = 1/n*X'X, 1/n*X'Y, 1/n*Y'Y
# moments[3] = mean(X'X'X), mean(X'X'Y), mean(X'Y'Y),
#   mean(Y'Y'Y)
# etc
def getRawMoments(data, moment, axis=0):
    a = moment
    if (axis==0):
        n = float(data.shape[1])
        X = matrix(data[0,:]).reshape((n,1))
        Y = matrix(data[1,:]).reshape((n,1))
    else:
        n = float(data.shape[0])
        X = matrix(data[:,0]).reshape((n,1))
        Y = matrix(data[:,1]).reshape((n,11))

    result = 1
    Z = hstack((X,Y))
    iota = ones((1,n))
    moments = {}
    moments[0] = 1
    #first, generate huge-ass matrix containing all x-y combinations
    # for every power-combination k,l such that k+l = i
    # for all 0 <= i <= a
    for i in arange(1,a):
        if i==2:
            moments[i] = moments[i-1]*Z
        # if even, postmultiply with X. 
        elif i%2 == 1:
            moments[i] = kron(moments[i-1], Z.T)
        # Else, postmultiply with X.T
        elif i%2==0:
            temp = moments[i-1]
            temp2 = temp[:,0:n]*Z
            temp3 = temp[:,n:2*n]*Z
            moments[i] = hstack((temp2, temp3)) 
    # since now we have many multiple moments
    # such as x**2*y and x*y*x, filter non-distinct elements
    momentsDistinct = {}
    momentsDistinct[0] = 1
    for i in arange(1,a):
        if i%2 == 0:
            data = 1/n*moments[i]
        elif i == 1:
            temp = moments[i]
            temp2 = temp[:,0:n]*iota.T
            data = 1/n*hstack((temp2))            
        else:
            temp = moments[i]
            temp2 = temp[:,0:n]*iota.T
            temp3 = temp[:,n:2*n]*iota.T
            data = 1/n*hstack((temp2, temp3))
        momentsDistinct[i] = unique(data.flat)
    return momentsDistinct(result, axis=1)
```

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.moment.html#scipy.stats.moment)?

Comment: Excellent. If you had set that up as an answer, I could close this .)

Comment: Note that this is univariate, it doesn't calculate a multivariate version of the moments. It's like numpy.var and not like numpy.cov for the second moment.

Comment: do you know the covariance of your multivariate distribution(s)?

Comment: Uh yeah, after trying to use it I saw that something was fishy. I need it multivariate. Well I don't "know" the covariance, but I could always compute it ... but that's what I hoped python would take from me.

Comment: You might want to add more details (just edit them into the question). Specifically, what exactly is the format of the data, what exactly you are trying to calculate (a formula would be useful), and why DIY (just writing out the formula) does not work for you.

Comment: Aye, updated the question

Comment: @FooBar "I kind of expected there to be some out-of-the-box thing to use as I thought this would be a standard problem."  I don't think that finding higher moments than covariance is usually standard.  I can only speak for myself that I've done this only once before and that was not with python but with R.

The problem is interesting and I was going to suggest [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isserlis%E2%80%99_theorem](Isserlis' theorem), but I really don't know what kind of data you have.

Comment: Okay, I will code it manually then - thanks for all the suggestions :)